# lombok builders does not care of restricted set of method/constructor-properties

Tags: builder, lombok

I have 3 builder methods:

```
@Builder(builderMethodName = "b1")
public static User builder1(String name, String age) {
    return User.b3().name(name).age(age).build();
}


@Builder(builderMethodName = "b2")
public User(String name, String date, String type) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.date = date;
    this.type = type;
}

@Builder(builderMethodName = "b3")
public User(String name, String age, String date, String type) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.date = date;
    this.type = type;
}
```

When I use `b1`-builder, I expect that only `name` and `age` properties can be set by this builder. However, using this also works (but it should not):

```
User.b1().name("a").age("1").date("12").type("b").build();
```

The same goes for `b2`-builder. The builder should only provide `name`, `date` and `type`, however the builders `b1` and `b2` support the same properties as `b3`, even though the declaration of these methods restrict it.

**How can I restrict the set properties of `b1` and `b2`-builder?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your `@Builder`s share the same builder class, because the name of that builder class is generated by concatenating the name of the *containing class* with `"Builder"`, i.e. it is always `"UserBuilder"` in this case. Thus, the different `@Builder`s all contribute their setter methods to that single builder class.

You have to let the different `@Builder`s generate different builders classes:

```
@Builder(builderClassName = "UserBuilder1", builderMethodName = "b1")
```